# Producing JSON in RESTful Web Service (GETTING WEIRD OUTPUT)

Tags: java, json, web-services, jax-rs, cxf

I am having trouble in producing JSON. I might be doing very silly mistake. 
Here is my code

```
    @GET
    @Path("/{accountid}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Consumes({"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})

    public List<Statement> getStatementsList(@PathParam("accountid") String account) throws Exception {

        Date fromDate = new Date();
        Date toDate = new Date();
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        toDate = today.getTime();
        today.add(Calendar.MONTH, -13);
        fromDate = today.getTime();
        ArrayList<Statement> statements = (ArrayList<Statement>) getStatements(account, null, toDate);
        return  statements;
    }
```

And here is my Statement class

```
package au.com.fxa.sfdc.Model;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class Statement
{
    private Date statementDate;
    private BigDecimal totalAmount;
    private String imageLocation;
    private String accountNumber;


    public Statement() {

    }

    public Date getStatementDate()
    {
        return this.statementDate;
    }

    public String getFormattedStatementDate()
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return sdf.format(this.statementDate);
    }

    public BigDecimal getTotalAmount()
    {
        return this.totalAmount;
    }

    public void setStatementDate(Date statementDate)
    {
        this.statementDate = statementDate;
    }

    public void setTotalAmount(BigDecimal totalAmount)
    {
        this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
    }

    public String getImageLocation()
    {
        return this.imageLocation;
    }

    public void setImageLocation(String imageLocation)
    {
        this.imageLocation = imageLocation;

    }

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }


    public String toString() {
        return "au.com.fxa.s21.custdoc.model.StatementBean{" +

                ", statementDate=" + statementDate +
                ", totalAmount=" + totalAmount +
                ", imageLocation='" + imageLocation + "'" +
                "}";
    }

}
```

I am getting 15 items in my statements list. But instead of JSON I am getting following output in browser

```
   No message body writer has been found for class java.util.ArrayList, ContentType: application/json
```

Comment: Did you want to JSON encode `statements` before returning?

Comment: I don't know what you mean here but I just want to see output in JSON format.